# MySQL - join two tables, searching in the second

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

guys,

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
UID    NAME
1      Name1
2      Name2
3      Name3
```

Table 2:

```
UID    PID    PARAM
1      1     10
2      1     20
3      2     10
4      2     30
5      2     40
6      3     60
7      3     20
8      3     10
```

I need to join the two tables (t1.UID=t2.PID) and to list only the records from the first table, that have (for example) BOTH PARAM=10 AND PARAM=20 in the second table. This way, for this example, the query should return:

```
UID      NAME
1        Name1
3        Name3
```

..because only Name1 AND Name3 have the BOTH PARAM=10 AND PARAM=20

How can I do this? I know it's probably very simple, but I can't find the answer nor here, neither in google.

Thank you in advance!
Ned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a.name          
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on (a.UID = b.PID)
where b.param in (10, 20)
group by a.name
having count(*) = 2
```

by declaring your table `table1 a`, you can call any columnfrom this table by putting the tables declared name in from of the column `a.name`

Comment: now it will be empty result cause param can't be 10 and 20 in the same row :)

Comment: Yes, I need to have only the records from the first table that have BOTH param=10 and param=20... e.g. it should return just Name1 and Name3, because Name2 has param=10, but it doesn't have param=20

Comment: try my edit there, this should only return ones that have both 10 and 20

Comment: sorry i had the column `name` as `names`, try again

Comment: yes, i changed the names, but it's the same... "Having count(*)=2" hides all the records.. and I'm not sure if this method is correct

Comment: it should work, maybe you have duplicate parameter values for the same pid ?

Comment: the edit above will work, the problem was with the UID, the UID should be PID and the PID should be UID in table2

Comment: yes, I found the problem - it was in here (a.UID = b.PID). Could you please explain me what's the idea of the Having Count(2)=2? What does it do and why you use it?

Comment: this will basically return all `a.name` that have a count of 2, so because name2 only has param=10 and not param=20 it will only appear once from `select a.name          
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on (a.UID = b.PID)
where b.param in (10, 20)`, where as name1 and name3 both have param=10 and param=20 so they both appear twice... so this means that `having count(*) = 2` will only return name1 and name3, not name2 as it only appears once... if the statement was `having count(*) <= 2` then name2 would also be returned

Answer (score 1):

This query should work:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT PID 
                 FROM table2  
                 WHERE PARAM IN(10, 20)
                 GROUP BY PID
                 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
                )t2
                ON t1.UID = t2.PID;
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution returns also Name2, which have PARAM=10, but doesn't have PARAM=20.. I need to have the records that have together PARAM=10 AND PARAM=20

Comment: The first one is not correct, it will return results if only 10 is there, for that satisfies `in (10,20)`. Check my query, hopefully it will work!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your solution is even much more better, because your way I can connect easier more tables like table2 and make a bigger search on different criteria!

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct t1.id 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.uid = t2.pid and t2.param = 10 
               join table2 t3 on t1.uid = t3.pid and t3.param = 20
```

Comment: Your solution is working, but is there more simple way to do this? I have many, many, many PARAMS in Table2 which should match the criteria. If the users checks 20 params I will have to make 20 joins... not to mention that I have to connect the same way (in the same query) more tables with matching criteria like Table 2 (but this will be easy if I success with one table)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to join:

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE UID IN (
  SELECT UID FROM TABLE2
  WHERE PARAM IN (10, 20)
)

Comment: Thanks, but your solution returns also Name2, which have PARAM=10, but doesn't have PARAM=20.. I need to have the records that have together PARAM=10 AND PARAM=20

Comment: Sorry, I understood your question in the way that want the lines with 10 OR 20.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select uid,name from t1 where exists (select 1 from t2 where param = 10 and pid = t1.uid) and exists (select 1 from t2 where param = 20 and pid = t1.uid);
```